# compare string in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I tried to write the following script to compare two HTML response headers, however i am hitting the `else` condition despite by printing the header stored in the variable `$a` I am getting the exact same value.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
echo "Connecting to www.cloudflare.com...";
curl -Is "https://www.cloudflare.com/" > file1.txt;
a=$(cat file1.txt | grep Server);
echo "$a";
echo
echo "Connecting directly to www.amazon.com...";
curl -Iks "https://www.amazon.com/" > file2.txt;
b=$(cat file2.txt | grep Server);
echo "$b";
echo

if [ "$a" == "Server: cloudflare-nginx" ]; then
    echo "This connection is going via CloudFlare"
else
    echo "This connection is NOT going via CloudFlare"
    echo "$a"
fi
```

Comment: Do you have output for your script too? I seem to get lower-case response for `server` header.

Comment: @steeldriver - I was just posting my answer with suggested change as you posted this comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header lines being returned from the `curl` commands have a `^M` before the newline. You could change the `if` to use a regex:

```
if [[ "$a" =~ "Server: cloudflare-nginx" ]]; then
    echo "This connection is going via CloudFlare"
else
    echo "This connection is NOT going via CloudFlare"
    echo "$a"
fi
```

You can also remove the `\r` by changing the line:

```
a=$(cat file1.txt | tr -d '\r' | grep '^Server:');
```